# Receptacle and two switches

Tags: receptacle

I have a single pole light switch controlling a receptacle. I want to add another light switch and control a ceiling fan.
There’s only a black and white at light switch(white at top and black on bottom).
Can i add another single pole switch off existing switch for ceiling fan?
Thanks for your time.

Comment: "Top" and "bottom" of what? The junction box? The switch terminals? The photograph you took of the inside of the box?

Comment: Is the fan a new installation or are you trying to add a switch for  an existing fan?

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of the boxes involved please?

Answer (score 2):

That sounds a lot like a switch loop,  in which case the answer is a hard no.

To switch the fan you'll need to run a cable to the switch location to deliver electric power and another wire from the switch location to the fan location.

Your other option would be to go to some sort of wireless switch, where there is a receiver in the fan and a transmitter at the switch location.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, in a group of "switch"(es) and "switched thing"(s), there is exactly one place where you can tap power for other things.  *And you don't get to decide where it is*.

In this case, power (i.e. supply hot and neutral) is not available at the switch.  If you want supply hot and neutral for other uses, you'll need to tap it somewhere else.

That said, if you want to abandon the switched receptacle and have the fan be a fan+light *instead* of the switched receptacle, then you can rewire the receptacle to be always-on, and re-task the "switch loop" to be always-hot and neutral to the switch.  Then, you can bring /3 cable from the switch to the new fan/light location.  The /3 cable (black white red bare-ground) allows separate control of light and fan.